# Problem with function in python causing a loop

Tags: python-3.x

When i run my code, it will run the part of player1 however once it reaches the function it will loop back and do the player1 section again, code for it is here:

```
import random
playerscore2 = 0

EvenNums = [2,4,6,8,10,12]
OddNums = [3,5,7,9,11]

def playerscoretwo():
         print("Player 2's turn")
         rolling2 = input('would you like to roll?')
         roll3 = rolling2.lower()
         
         if rolling2 == 'Yes':
          playerscore3 = 0
          die3 = random.randint(1,6)
          print('You got: ' +str(die3))
          playerscore3 = int(playerscore3) + int(die3)
          roll4 = input('Would you like to roll again?') 
          if roll4 == 'Yes':
    
           die4 = random.randint(1,6)
           print('You got: ' +str(die4))
           playerscore4 = int(playerscore3) + int(die4)
           int(playerscore4)
           
           if playerscore3 in EvenNums:
             playerscore4 = int(playerscore3) + 10
             print("Player 2's total score is: " +str(playerscore4))
           
           elif playerscore3 in OddNums:
             playerscore4 = int(playerscore3) - 5
             print("Player 2's total score is: " +str(playerscore4))
           
           else:
            print('Wrong input, please restart the game')
     
          else:
           print('Wrong input, please restart the game')
      







while True:
 print("Player 1's turn")
 rolling = input('would you like to roll?').lower()




if rolling == 'yes':
 playerscore1 = 0
 die1 = random.randint(1,6)
 print('You got: ' +str(die1))
 playerscore1 = int(playerscore1) + int(die1)
 roll2 = input('Would you like to roll again?').lower()
 if roll2 == 'yes':
    
     die2 = random.randint(1,6)
     print('You got: ' +str(die2))
     playerscore1 = int(playerscore1) + int(die2)
     int(playerscore1)
     
     if playerscore1 in EvenNums:
         playerscore2 = int(playerscore1) + 10
         print("Player 1's total score is: " +str(playerscore2))
         
         #player 2 section, p1 evennum 
         playerscoretwo()
      
     elif playerscore1 in OddNums:
         playerscore2 = int(playerscore1) - 5
         print("Player 1's total score is: " +str(playerscore2))
         
         #player 2 section, player 1 oddnum
         playerscoretwo()
         
      
      
     else:
         print('Wrong input, please restart the game')
      #note, section will be copy pasted with certain variables changed to make code easier to write, 
and easier to test
 else:
      print('Wrong input, please restart the game')
     

elif rolling == 'no':
   break

else:
  print('Wrong input, please restart the game')
```

I have attempted to not use functions at all, however indentation becomes a drastic problem and will not run at all, even if it is a plain copy paste.

If anyone has any idea on what the problem is, it'd be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question the issue is - indentation

your

```
while True:
 print("Player 1's turn")
 rolling = input('would you like to roll?').lower()
```

is at the same indent level with

```
if rolling == 'yes':
```

so it never actually reaches that part since it's always runs the while loop, so you probably should put your if statement and everything that follows under the while loop.

Also as a suggestion, consider refactoring this code a bit and extract common pieces into reusable parametrized functions and call them instead, this way it would be much easier to read for everyone including yourself and since it will reduce the duplication and code amount chances that you will fall into a similar trap slightly reduce